# FFMPEG delay mutliple overlay videos (with different delays)

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to overlay a video (for example a report) with different other videos or images, like hints to the facebook page or a hint to the website. These other videos or images are smaller than the original and sometimes transparent (rgba).

I already tried to overlay multiple videos, which works pretty well:

`ffmpeg -i 30fps_fhd.mp4 -i sample.mp4 -i timer.webm -i logo.jpg -filter_complex "overlay = x=100:y=1000, overlay = x=30:y=66:eof_action=pass, overlay = x=0:y=0" -acodec copy -t 70 out.mp4`

But now, I want to start some videos or images not at the beginning of the video, instead after a period of time.
I found flags like 'itsoffset' or 'setpts', but I dont know how to apply them on this 'multiple video / image overlay command'.

LG Bamba

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found out how it works. I have to take the input with [index:v] apply effects on it (separated with commas) and save it in a variable (add [var-name] at the end of the effect-chain). Then you can apply the overlay effect, by putting two variables (if not edited, then the input variable -> [index:v]) next to each other and write the effect-metadata next to them.